# How to stream video(local video file) from an android phone to different android phones

Tags: streaming, rtsp, rtp

I am trying to establish multimedia streaming among multiple android devices. Where all of them play a synchronized video. An good example of my idea is Samsung video group play. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Any solution to this question? I kinda want the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Google how to implement an RTSP server on the host device and then all of the client devices can connect to the RTSP stream. For the synchronization matter - either use multicast or server the same payload with adjusted timestamps to all the clients.

Comment: Can you elaborate little more please?